# Prove that the order on integers is antisymmetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> Let $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $m  \le  n  \le  m$ then $m = n$.

The definition of order is: if $m>n$ it means $m-n \in\mathbb{N}$.

I know that by definition this means either $m<n$ and $n<m$ or $m=n$, but I'm having trouble proving $m=n$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\le$?  Do you know it is antisymmetric?  Presumably not, because this is proving it.  We have to know what you have available to prove this.

Comment: @NasuSama I know that by definition this means either m<n and n<m or m=n, but I'm having trouble proving m=n.

Comment: @RossMillikan If m>n it means m-n$ \in \mathbb{N}$. If m $\ge$ n it means m>n or m=n.

Comment: Now, the statement seems reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

You are given $(m \lt n) \vee (m=n)$, so assume $m \lt n$.  Can you show $n \not \lt m$?

Comment: That makes it easy to prove $n \not \lt m$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

By assuming $n\neq m$, you have either $n<m$ or $m<n$. Then assume one of it, say $n<m$, together with $n\geq m$. Can you get a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

$m\leq n\leq m$ implies:

$1.$ $m$ is **less than** or **equal** to $n$

$2.$ $m$ is **greater than** or **equal** to $n$

Taking the intersection of the above two conditions, we get $m=n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just start at the most complex side and do what comes naturally:
\begin{align}
& m \le n \;\land\; n \le m \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"basic property of $\;\le\;$, twice -- to introduce $\;=\;$ as in our goal"} \\
& (m < n \lor m = n) \;\land\; (n < m \lor n = m) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: factor out $\;m = n\;$ using distribution"} \\
& (m < n \;\land\; n < m) \lor m = n \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"... -- to get rid of the left hand part"} \\
& \ldots &
\end{align}
Can you finish this calculation, given the rules you know about $\;<\;$?